Ordering Firestore documents using a nested field
Trying out Firestore REST API, the documentation states that to order items ?orderBy=name%20desc this orders using the document name in descending order. The documents I need to order have the following structure
{
  "name": "document_name",
  "fields":{
    "createTime": "2024-08-23T23:06:05.206209Z",
  }
}

How could I order using the createTime field? since doing ?orderBy=fields.createTime returns empty JSON.

Removed the google-cloud-firestore tag since using ?orderBy= in the query string is the way used to filter with the RTDB REST API

Hey mbithi. Is it the Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore?

it's cloud firestore

As far as I know, Firestore REST API doesn't allow ordering directly on nested fields (like fields.createTime) as you are trying to do right now. However, this technique will only work if you use mobile or web SDKs.
So to solve this, I recommend you modify the structure of your document so that createTime becomes a top-level field in the document and not a nested one:
{
  "name": "document_name",
  "createTime": "2024-08-23T23:06:05.206209Z", //
  "fields": {
    //Other fields.
  }
}

Because in your current document, inside the fields field, I cannot see other fields besides the createTime, a nesting structure is not beneficial at all. Please also note, that when it comes to using date and time, it's best to use a Firestore timestamp. You're currently storing the date and time as a string, which may lead to a Lexicographic order. To better understand please check my answer to the following question:

How to order data from Firestore in Flutter, orderBy not ordering correct


Hi Alex, I think the OP is using the RTDB: ?orderBy= is the way used to filter with the RTDB REST API

it's actually cloud firestore, and orderBy parameter orders the documents just fine using the field provided,

Good to hear that :) So did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

is there a way I can get all documents without the pagination token?

That seems to be another question that is not related to the initial one. So please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own MCVE, so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

So can I help you with other information regarding the initial question?

@mbithi Can you please share the entire URL you use to call the rest API (and not only the ?orderBy=fields.createTime part). Thanks
